# Glimpse MVC3 disappearing for ViewMOdel page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, glimpse

I have a view that is strongly typed to a view model, and has started running really slowly since I made some code update this morning.  I installed Glimpse MVC to see if I could get a better idea about what might be happening.  Glimpse works on every page except the ViewModel page - the tab disappears without outputting any information.

My Glimpse log file says:

```
2012-06-22 13:50:29.5831|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|BeginRequest handling complete for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:29.5851|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|get_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-06-22 13:50:29.5851|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|set_Binders method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-06-22 13:50:29.5851|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|GetType method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-06-22 13:50:29.6101|WARN|Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Execution|MemberwiseClone method of System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker type is not proxyable.|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5192|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|PostRequestHandlerExecute handling complete for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5212|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|PostReleaseRequestState handling complete for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5462|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Plumbing.GlimpseSerializer|Serializer error|System.ObjectDisposedException--The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.--   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContract collectionValueContract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteMemberInfoProperty(JsonWriter writer, Object memberValue, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContract collectionValueContract)
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5602|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Plumbing.GlimpseSerializer|Serializer error|System.ObjectDisposedException--The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.--   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContract collectionValueContract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.WriteMemberInfoProperty(JsonWriter writer, Object memberValue, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContract collectionValueContract)
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5602|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|Glimpse JSON payload created for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5702|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|Glimpse output generated for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5702|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|RequestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results) persisted|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.5702|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|EndRequest handling complete for requestId 64d0e726-a756-4c1a-a9c4-629231948aa2 (/SurveyResponse/Results)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.6272|INFO|Glimpse.Core.Module|BeginRequest handling complete for requestId 44be221e-a7e2-4ac7-bd4c-29ae2b9ad12f (/Glimpse.axd)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.6422|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Validator.GlimpseRequestValidator|Glimpse.Core.Validator.ContentTypeValidator invalided request (it will now be ignored) with id 44be221e-a7e2-4ac7-bd4c-29ae2b9ad12f (/Glimpse.axd)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.6482|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Validator.GlimpseRequestValidator|Glimpse.Core.Validator.ContentTypeValidator invalided request (it will now be ignored) with id 44be221e-a7e2-4ac7-bd4c-29ae2b9ad12f (/Glimpse.axd)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.6482|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Validator.GlimpseRequestValidator|Glimpse.Core.Validator.ContentTypeValidator invalided request (it will now be ignored) with id 44be221e-a7e2-4ac7-bd4c-29ae2b9ad12f (/Glimpse.axd)|
2012-06-22 13:50:30.6642|WARN|Glimpse.Core.Validator.GlimpseRequestValidator|Glimpse.Core.Validator.ContentTypeValidator invalided request (it will now be ignored) with id 44be221e-a7e2-4ac7-bd4c-29ae2b9ad12f (/Glimpse.axd)|
```

The code that caused the poor performance was adding these Select statements inside of my group by query:

```
 var data = from SurveyResponseModel in db.SurveyResponseModels
                       group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
                       select new ResultsViewModel()
                       {
                           MemberId = resultCount.Key,
                           PatientFollowUpResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp),
                           ChangeCodingPracticeResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(r => r.ChangeCodingPractice),

                           ChangesOthersResult = resultCount.Select(r => r.ChangesOthers),

                           YesBarriersOthersResult = resultCount.Select(r => r.YesBarriersOthers),

                           AddressBarriersOthersResult = resultCount.Select(r => r.AddressBarriersOthers),
                           TotalResponsesResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(),
                       };
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the bit of code that you changed?

Comment: Ok, the slow loading code has been added.

Comment: I would recommend re-posting question, or re-titling and editing the question to highlight that the actual problem is a slow performing linq-to-entities query. The bit about MVC and glimpse I don't think has anything to do with your actual issue.

Comment: Also, have you tried SQL profiling the execution of the linq query?

Comment: I am using SQL Compact and I didn't think this was possible.  Is there an option to do that?

Comment: Uff SQL CE, no there isn't really a great way to profile it. Why are you using SQL CE for a web app?

Comment: You know, you're right.  I should just switch over to SQL Server 2008R2 and save myself more potential Headaching.

Comment: Also SQL CE is not threadsafe and supports max 256 concurrent connections, not a good DB for a web app.

Answer (score 0):

I would say what is happening here is that Glimpse is triggering the lazy loading of a property in your model. Unfortunately Glimpae doesn't support this case at the current time. To test if this this the case, try and disable the view tab and see if you have the same problem.